# Spark Job succeded in Airflow but no result seeing in Spark UI

Tags: pyspark, airflow, spark-submit

I'm beginner with airflow and spark and I am currently setting up a data pipeline locally using Airflow and Spark.
The DAG I want to do has just one task that runs a pyspark job on Spark.

The dags folder of my application contains two files:

**dag-airflow-spark-submitop.py :**

```
import airflow
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators.spark_submit_operator import SparkSubmitOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'moi',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'retries': 5,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=30),
    'start_date': datetime(year=2023, month=7, day=9),
}

with airflow.DAG('dag_teste_spark_connection', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='0 1 * * *') as dag:
    task_elt_documento_pagar = SparkSubmitOperator(
        task_id='task_run_pysparkjob',
        conn_id='spark',
        application="./dags/sparkjob.py",
    )
```

**sparkjob.py :**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("test") \
    .getOrCreate()

data = [("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.show()
```

So the first step it's to run my Spark service (master and worker), in the localhost:8080 like that :
[image: Spark UI]

And then Airflow :
[image: airflow UI]

In the UI we can see my DAG "dag_teste_spark_connection".

And here my Spark connection :
[image]

The problem is that when I run the DAG I have a success in the UI but I can't see the job done in Spark UI :
[image: success dag]

As you can see in this screeshot, I don't have Completed Applications :
[image: spark result]

here are the details of my task after I clicked the toggle button :
[image: task details]

And here the task logs :

```
*** Found local files:
***   * /opt/airflow/logs/dag_id=dag_teste_spark_connection/run_id=manual__2023-07-09T14:53:27.424066+00:00/task_id=task_run_pysparkjob/attempt=1.log
[2023-07-09, 14:53:37 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1103} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=non-requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: dag_teste_spark_connection.task_run_pysparkjob manual__2023-07-09T14:53:27.424066+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-07-09, 14:53:37 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1103} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: dag_teste_spark_connection.task_run_pysparkjob manual__2023-07-09T14:53:27.424066+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-07-09, 14:53:37 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1308} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 6
[2023-07-09, 14:53:37 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1327} INFO - Executing <Task(SparkSubmitOperator): task_run_pysparkjob> on 2023-07-09 14:53:27.424066+00:00
[2023-07-09, 14:53:37 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:57} INFO - Started process 278 to run task
[2023-07-09, 14:53:37 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:84} INFO - Running: ['***', 'tasks', 'run', 'dag_teste_spark_connection', 'task_run_pysparkjob', 'manual__2023-07-09T14:53:27.424066+00:00', '--job-id', '98', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/dag-***-spark-submitop.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpuzlf2_yf']
[2023-07-09, 14:53:37 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:85} INFO - Job 98: Subtask task_run_pysparkjob
[2023-07-09, 14:53:37 UTC] {task_command.py:410} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: dag_teste_spark_connection.task_run_pysparkjob manual__2023-07-09T14:53:27.424066+00:00 [running]> on host ef29c1050b71
[2023-07-09, 14:53:37 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1547} INFO - Exporting env vars: AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER='moi' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID='dag_teste_spark_connection' AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID='task_run_pysparkjob' AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE='2023-07-09T14:53:27.424066+00:00' AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER='1' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID='manual__2023-07-09T14:53:27.424066+00:00'
[2023-07-09, 14:53:37 UTC] {base.py:73} INFO - Using connection ID 'spark' for task execution.
[2023-07-09, 14:53:37 UTC] {spark_submit.py:339} INFO - Spark-Submit cmd: spark-submit --master spark://MacBook-Pro-de-AdminSensei-9.local:7077:7077 --name arrow-spark ./dags/sparkjob.py
[2023-07-09, 14:53:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - /home/***/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/bin/load-spark-env.sh: line 68: ps: command not found
[2023-07-09, 14:53:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - JAVA_HOME is not set
[2023-07-09, 14:53:38 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1824} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/spark/operators/spark_submit.py", line 157, in execute
    self._hook.submit(self._application)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/spark/hooks/spark_submit.py", line 422, in submit
    f"Cannot execute: {self._mask_cmd(spark_submit_cmd)}. Error code is: {returncode}."
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Cannot execute: spark-submit --master spark://MacBook-Pro-de-AdminSensei-9.local:7077:7077 --name arrow-spark ./dags/sparkjob.py. Error code is: 1.
[2023-07-09, 14:53:38 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1350} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY. dag_id=dag_teste_spark_connection, task_id=task_run_pysparkjob, execution_date=20230709T145327, start_date=20230709T145337, end_date=20230709T145338
[2023-07-09, 14:53:38 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:109} ERROR - Failed to execute job 98 for task task_run_pysparkjob (Cannot execute: spark-submit --master spark://MacBook-Pro-de-AdminSensei-9.local:7077:7077 --name arrow-spark ./dags/sparkjob.py. Error code is: 1.; 278)
[2023-07-09, 14:53:38 UTC] {local_task_job_runner.py:225} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2023-07-09, 14:53:38 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2651} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Your dag seems to be paused in the ui.  Make it active by pressing the toggle button

Answer (score 1):

New dags by default are paused. To acrivate it press the toggle button next to your  dag name in Dags page.

In the screenshots you attached you can see that all your dags are paused and also the task is not in success mode (not green)

Comment: when I press the play button, I don't get the impression that the task is being carried out successfully. It also seems to go into up_for_retry.

Comment: you can check the logs, press the task and "log" or from the grid view select the task.

Comment: I edited the topic with the audit logs. it seems that the task fails.

Comment: please, add the task log (not the dag audit logs) to get more info

Comment: oh yes sorry I updated the topic. Normally it's the log for my last run